# Swift : pressed label to copy text to the clipboard

Tags: swift, button, label, clipboard

I want to save a text to the clipboard when pressing on a label.

I've tried UIPasteboard but is not recognized by Xcode 7

So basically I'm stuck on the really basic:

```
@IBAction func label1(sender: AnyObject) {

}
```

Answer (score 9):

XCode 8 and Swift 3 code looks like the following to copy text to the clipboard:

```
UIPasteboard.general.string = "this is your text"
```

Answer (score 2):

If it is just text use this code snipet:

```
UIPasteboard.generalPasteboard().string = "Label text"
```

Comment: Hi Oleg, thanks for your answer, I've tried that alright but have "use of unresolved identifier "UIPasteboard"

Comment: UIPasteboard.general.string = "Label Text"

Answer (score 1):

```
let pasteBoard = NSPasteboard.generalPasteboard()
pasteBoard.clearContents()
pasteBoard.setString("my string", forType: NSStringPboardType)
```

Answer (score 0):

This code work for me:

```
 let pasteboard = UIPasteboard.general
 pasteboard.string = lableGetPassword.text
```